# HTTP Error 404 when trying to browse aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to browse some aspx pages which are part of MVC application.
I have tried the usual steps such as installing asp.net using aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable to no avail.

Weird things is that its working fine in the development environment but failing in our UAT environment. Same machine/environment as far as I can see. Only difference I can see is that when I look at the contents view in IIS for the folder holding the aspx pages, on dev the type of the files says ASP.NET Server Page whereas on UAT it says ASPX File. Everything else seems to be the same on both machines.

Server details: Windows Server 2008R2 Standard Service Pack 1

All help greatfully appreciated.

Comment: In IIS "Request Filtering", have you denied aspx files?

Comment: No. There are a few in the list bu aspx is not one of them.